# How can I align tables of different lengths?

Tags: tables, tabularx, minipage

How can i align both of these tables so that the first row start on the same line? Currently, I have the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c c c|}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
cell10 & cell11 & cell12 \\
\hline
cell13 & cell14 & cell15 \\
\hline
cell16 & cell17 & cell18 \\
\hline
cell19 & cell20 & cell21 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c c c|}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
cell10 & cell11 & cell12 \\
\hline
cell13 & cell14 & cell15 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

and current output is
[image]

Comment: I think that adding the option `[t]` (top alignment) to both `minipage`s and `tabular`s would do the trick. Something like `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}\begin{tabular}[t]{|c c c|}...`

Comment: Actually, [t] will align the \hline when first.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c c c|}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
cell10 & cell11 & cell12 \\
\hline
cell13 & cell14 & cell15 \\
\hline
cell16 & cell17 & cell18 \\
\hline
cell19 & cell20 & cell21 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c c c|}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
cell10 & cell11 & cell12 \\
\hline
cell13 & cell14 & cell15 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code uses two minipages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c c c|}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
cell10 & cell11 & cell12 \\
\hline
cell13 & cell14 & cell15 \\
\hline
cell16 & cell17 & cell18 \\
\hline
cell19 & cell20 & cell21 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c c c|}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
\hline
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
\hline
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
\hline
cell10 & cell11 & cell12 \\
\hline
cell13 & cell14 & cell15 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for answering the question. i did try using this method and it initially worked but now its breaking for some reason but i'm not sure why. could you please help

Comment: @texstar, you are welcome. My latex code still works in my computer generating the above picture. It's different from your newly posted code. Your code has two minipages. Mine uses only one.

Comment: is there any way to get it to work with two minipages?

Comment: @texstar, Sure. I just updated my answer.